# Counting the historical view of open files

Tags: excel, date, count

Good morning,

I'm trying to get an historical count on files going back two years, regardless of their status now. The files have 4 dates that will factor into this (Created, Closed, Reopened and Reclosed) my thought was to find the Monday of the week in relation to dates above, this would give me the last time it could have been Open / Re-Opened. Formula Below -

```
=IF(A2="open",B2-WEEKDAY(B2,3),IF(A2="reopened",D2-WEEKDAY(D2,3),IF(A2="Closed",C2-WEEKDAY(C2,3),IF(A2="Re-closed",E2-WEEKDAY(E2,3)))))
```

I figured from this I could find out what the active work in progress was at the start of any given Monday - however I'm struggling to figure out how to calculate this - or if is even possible? my first though was that `=Countif(` would work but not having any luck.

Does anybody know how or experienced a similar challenge before?

[image: Example of the workbook]

Edit for comment (Example) -

[image: Example]

This is a small example with the desired output to the right.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate exactly? The previous monday based on a given date? Your question is unclear. Are you trying to count dates or something? Or the minimun Monday value or what? When you mean *Counting the historical view of open files* it's kind of unclear

Comment: So wanting to know what the count would have been on a Monday - only looking at what would have been classed as open / reopened prior or on that date (Monday)

So last Monday (05/04) what would have been the count of files that were open . reopened.

If that makes sense?

Comment: Can you please post an expected output as example?

Comment: I've added an example in my first post with the desired output

Comment: Not sure, but if you are trying to count how many dates are in between 2 specific dates, in columns "Created,Closed,Reopened,Reclosed", something like `COUNTIFS(range of dates,">=29/03/2021", range of dates, "<=04/04/2021"` will count how many dates are in between `29/03/2021 - 04/04/2021`